# Having trouble rendering validation errors in view specific to input type

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, partials

I am attempting to get my validation errors to show up with only the message type the relate to.  There are three types of messages and I'm using javascript to show or hide the correct type.  I have tried to use type specific instance variables but when the validation fails, it won't read my instance variable correctly.

My controller function as it currently stands:

```
def create
    @user = current_user
    @errors = "errors"

    @sassy  = SassyWish.new
    @nice   = NiceWish.new
    @blank  = BlankWish.new

    if params[:sassy_wish]
        @wish = SassyWish.new sassy_params
    elsif params[:nice_wish]
        @wish = NiceWish.new nice_params
    elsif params[:blank_wish]
        @wish = BlankWish.new blank_params
    else
        render :new
    end

    @wish.save
    if @wish.errors.any?
        render :new
        @user = current_user
        if @wish._type = "SassyWish"
            @sassyErrors = @errors
        elsif @wish._type = "NiceWish"
            @niceErrors = "errors"
        elsif @wish._type = "BlankWish"
            @blankErrors = "errors"
        else
            @errors
        end
    else
        redirect_to wishes_url
    end
end
```

My view

```
<div class="gw_wish">
  <div class="gw_newWish">
    <div class="gw_start gw_new"></div>
    <div class="gw_newSassy gw_new">
      <%= render partial: @sassyErrors %>
         <%= render partial: "sassyWish" %>
    </div>
    <div class="gw_newNice gw_new">
        <%= render partial: "niceWish" %>
    </div>
    <div class="gw_newBlank gw_new">
        <%= render partial: "blankWish" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like the errors to show within each wish type so that when you click from one to another, it doesn't show if the wish type doesn't match the one submitted.

Currently I'm getting an error reading: 'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `==` instead of `=`. You are getting error because `@sassyErrors` is set as nil. Its not getting set because of the incorrect condition. Ditto for `@niceErrors` and `@blankErrors`.

```
if @wish.save   ## Check if record was saved successfully or not
    redirect_to wishes_url
else    
    @user = current_user
    if @wish._type == "SassyWish"
        @sassyErrors = @errors
    elsif @wish._type == "NiceWish"
        @niceErrors = "errors"
    elsif @wish._type == "BlankWish"
        @blankErrors = "errors"
    else
        @errors
    end
    render :new
end
```